# Need help getting started with a complicated limits problem

Tags: calculus, limits

So I've got this thing

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2+6x}-3}{x-3}$

I tried rationalizing but then it ended up in a huge mess and I didn't get the correct answer. I don't know if there's something else to do before resorting to rationalization. I just need something to get started.

Aside from that I know that something on the numerator will cancel out because if I evaluate the limit it ends up as $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: Use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Don't know what that is yet. This is my third day in class.

Comment: I would try rationalizing, as you mentioned.  Multiply by $(x^2+6x)^{2/3}+3(x^2+6x)^{1/3}+9$ on the top and bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2+6x}-3}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2+6x}-3\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{(x^2+6x)^2}+3\sqrt[3]{x^2+6x}+9\right)}{\left(x-3\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{(x^2+6x)^2}+3\sqrt[3]{x^2+6x}+9\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x^2+6x-27}{\left(x-3\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{(x^2+6x)^2}+3\sqrt[3]{x^2+6x}+9\right)}=\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x+9}{\sqrt[3]{(x^2+6x)^2}+3\sqrt[3]{x^2+6x}+9}$$

Comment: I see, this is what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Element118 Thank you for noticing the typo. I have fixed it.